# Crystal Report 2013 get most frequent value

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I've a crystal report with a data set of values like.
{1,2,3,3,3,3,4,5}
I need to get the most frequent value in the set which is (3)
how to perform this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **Numeric Summary Calculation Options** (you can use it in a **Formula Field**) you can use **MODE**

```
MODE that is the most frequentl used value in the field
```